# removechild loop exits before finish

Tags: javascript, dom

I have the following piece of code that finds all elements in the document with classname foo and then removes them all

```
        function(doc) {
            var items = doc.getElementsByClassName('foo');
            alert(items.length);
            if(items.length>0) {
                for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++) {
                    alert(i);
                    doc.body.removeChild(items[i]);
                }
        }
```

Forexample, the items.length is 3 and the function exits after running one loop and when the length is 8 it exits at 3. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also, when I run the function again and again it does eventually remove all elements.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that `items` is a **live** `NodeList`, i.e. whenever you access a property of the list (`items.length`), the list is reevaluated (elements are searched again).
Since you delete elements in the meantime, the list becomes shorter, but you keep the index.

You could convert the `NodeList` to an array first:

```
var items = [].slice.call(doc.getElementsByClassName('foo'));
```

The array size won't change when you delete the DOM elements.

Answer (score 12):

Your problem is that the `NodeList` returned by `getElementsByClassName()` is live. Either convert it into an array first as Felix suggests or iterate backwards:

```
var items = doc.getElementsByClassName('foo');
var i = items.length;
while (i--) {
    items[i].parentNode.removeChild(items[i]);
}
```

This works because the item removed from the list each iteration is the last item in the list, therefore not affecting earlier items.

I also changed `doc.body` to `items[i].parentNode` for greater generality, in case you need to deal with elements that are not direct children of the `<body>` element.