# nodeName being returned as "#text" when IF statement isn't commented out

Tags: javascript

Bit of a weird glitch here.

The tag name of a `childNode` is logged correctly when an IF statement is commented out, but as soon as you uncomment the IF statement then `childNode`s tag names are logged as "`#TEXT`".

```
<body>
    <div id="page_Wrapper">
        <h1>h1</h1>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <b>b</b>
        <br />
        <i>i</i>
        <br />
        <u>u</u>
        <div>div</div>
        <span>span</span>
    </div>

    <script>
        window.onLoad = removeTags();

        function removeTags(){
            var allTags = document.getElementById("page_Wrapper").childNodes;
            console.log("allTags length: " + allTags.length);

            for (var i = 0; i < allTags.length; i++){
                var tag = allTags[i].nodeName.toLowerCase();
                console.log(tag);
            /*
                if (tag != "b" || tag != "br" || tag != "i"){
                    allTags[i].parentNode.removeChild(allTags[i]);
                }
            */
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MythOfEchelon/VpNWA/3/

**Finished, working code:**

```
<body>
    <div id="page_Wrapper">
        <h1>h1</h1>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <b>b</b>
        <br />
        <i>i</i>
        <br />
        <u>u</u>
        <div>div</div>
        <span>span</span>
    </div>

    <script>
        window.onload = removeTags;

        function removeTags(){
            var allTags = document.getElementById("page_Wrapper").childNodes;
            var i = allTags.length;

            while (i--){
                var tag = allTags[i].nodeName.toLowerCase();
                console.log(tag);

                if (tag != "b" && tag != "br" && tag != "i"){
                    allTags[i].parentNode.removeChild(allTags[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: In future please include all relevant code in your post and **don't** just include a link to jsFiddle. Your post should standalone from any other resource; consider what'd happen if jsFiddle went down in the future.

Comment: The thing about NodeList objects is that they're **live**.  When you remove elements, the node list reflects that.

Comment: @Matt Sorry. My code logs to the console, so I thought it would be better to include a link to a live example, rather than inconveniencing people. I'll include the source code now.

Comment: Your `window.onLoad = removeTags();` is not doing what you think. You'll want `window.onload = removeTags;`. Note that the property is `onload`, not `onLoad` (JavaScript is case sensitive). The reason `removeTags` is still getting executed was because you're added `()` when you shouldn't have; what you were *actually* doing was executing `removeTags()` and setting the returned value (`undefined`) to `window.onLoad`. What you should be doing is setting `window.onload` to be a reference to the `removeTags` function.

Comment: But changing the line to `window.onload = removeTags;` still results in the same weird "`#TEXT`"-returning glitch. And I've never experienced any weird issues with changing case with event listeners, such as with `onClick`, `onKeyUp`, etc. :S

Comment: @BenHooper: Sorry yeah, it was a bit of additional advice rather than a fix for your problem; hence it being a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @Matt Oh, right. I see. Thanks. I've actually been wondering about that for a while. :L

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see The condition `(tag != "b" || tag != "br" || tag != "i")` selects *any* node (it maybe should be `(tag != "b" && tag != "br" && tag != "i") instead).` So the removeChild function is called on every loop.

If `allTags[i].parentNode.removeChild(allTags[i]);` is replaced by

```
var x = allTags[i];
x.parentNode.removeChild(x);
```

the behaviour is different. See also this: [removechild loop exits before finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148066/removechild-loop-exits-before-finish)

Comment: Somehow, using the answer from the linked question and using logical ANDs worked. I don't quite understand how, but it works. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line to check if it is a text node

```
for (...) {
    if (allTags[i].nodeType == 3) continue; //nodeType = 3 means it is a text node
    ...
}
```